# Badlogic package errors while not using it. In libgdx/java

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

I'm making a a game in java/libgdx. When I run the code in the desktop launcher it gives me a bunch of errors. All the errors comes from the badlogic default package.

My problem is this:

```
package com.wyvern.paperplane.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.wyvern.paperplane.PaperPlane;

public class DesktopLauncher {
public static void main (String[] args) {
  LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new       
  LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
  cfg.title = "my game";
  cfg.useGL30 = true;
  cfg.width = 720;
  cfg.height = 1280;
  new LwjglApplication(new PaperPlane(), cfg);
    } 
}
```

I don't understand why it gives me all the default badlogic errors while I only use my own package.

Here are some of the errors, note that i don't use any of the com.badlogic:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: badlogic.jpg

at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.(Texture.java:92)

at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.(Texture.java:88)

at com.wyvern.paperplane.PaperPlane.create(PaperPlane.java:16)

at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)

at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120) Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: badlogic.jpg (Internal)

at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)

at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)

at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.(Pixmap.java:137)
```

Comment: can you post the beginning of your stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: badlogic.jpg
```

Check for **badlogic.jpg** file and usage as mentioned in your error log.

By default there is a code line in main class that libGDX creates (as I see from your code and error log it must be under core/src/com/wyvern/paperplane/PaperPlane.java in line 16)

```
 img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
```

which creates a Texture using badlogic.jpg. And there are 2 badlogic.jpg files located in:

- desktop/bin/badlogic.jpg
- android/assets/badlogic.jpg

If you deleted them you should remove the code line mentioned above in your main class.

Comment: img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg"); this was the default I was looking for, changed it and it worked, thanks